# What Pandoc `markdown_github` and markdown_mmd` formats features caused to prevent from converting the raw markdown inside the HTML code?

Tags: html, markdown, pandoc

I am writing a Markdown file, using Codebraid Pandoc and Pandoc. I mix Markdown and HTML codes on the Markdown file.

On the Markdown, the raw HTML inside the Markdown code works, but the raw Markdown inside the HTML code does not work.

Here is the tiny Markdown code:

```
<section>

   # Set the _shell_ 
   ## Install the _shell_ [#](#install-the-shell){.anchor}
</section>
```

The raw Markdown, in a HTML code, was not converted. Observe that I have already `markdown_in_html_blocks`.

Here is the small YAML `defaults` file:

```yaml
# markdown_github
from: markdown_github-ascii_identifiers-east_asian_line_breaks+four_space_rule-grid_tables-ignore_line_breaks-implicit_figures-multiline_tables-literate_haskell-native_divs-native_spans-old_dashes-smart-tex_math_dollars-tex_math_single_backslash-wikilinks_title_after_pipe-wikilinks_title_before_pipe+abbreviations+all_symbols_escapable+angle_brackets_escapable+auto_identifiers+autolink_bare_uris+backtick_code_blocks+blank_before_blockquote+blank_before_header+bracketed_spans+citations+compact_definition_lists+definition_lists+emoji+escaped_line_breaks+example_lists+fancy_lists+fenced_code_attributes+fenced_code_blocks+fenced_divs+footnotes+gfm_auto_identifiers+gutenberg+hard_line_breaks+header_attributes+implicit_header_references+inline_code_attributes+inline_notes-intraword_underscores+latex_macros+line_blocks+link_attributes+lists_without_preceding_blankline+mark+markdown_attribute+markdown_in_html_blocks+mmd_header_identifiers+mmd_link_attributes+mmd_title_block+pandoc_title_block+pipe_tables+raw_attribute+raw_html+raw_tex+rebase_relative_paths+short_subsuperscripts+shortcut_reference_links+simple_tables+space_in_atx_header+spaced_reference_links+startnum+strikeout+subscript+superscript+table_captions+task_lists+tex_math_double_backslash+yaml_metadata_block

# markdown_mmd
from: markdown_mmd-ascii_identifiers-east_asian_line_breaks-grid_tables-implicit_figures-literate_haskell-native_divs-native_spans-old_dashes-smart-tex_math_single_backslash-wikilinks_title_after_pipe-wikilinks_title_before_pipe+abbreviations+all_symbols_escapable+angle_brackets_escapable+auto_identifiers+autolink_bare_uris+backtick_code_blocks+blank_before_blockquote+blank_before_header+bracketed_spans+citations+compact_definition_lists+definition_lists+emoji+escaped_line_breaks+example_lists+fancy_lists+fenced_code_attributes+fenced_code_blocks+fenced_divs+footnotes+four_space_rule+gfm_auto_identifiers+gutenberg+hard_line_breaks+header_attributes+ignore_line_breaks+implicit_header_references+inline_code_attributes+inline_notes+intraword_underscores+latex_macros+line_blocks+link_attributes+lists_without_preceding_blankline+mark+markdown_attribute+markdown_in_html_blocks+mmd_header_identifiers+mmd_link_attributes+mmd_title_block+multiline_tables+pandoc_title_block+pipe_tables+raw_attribute+raw_html+raw_tex+rebase_relative_paths+short_subsuperscripts+shortcut_reference_links+simple_tables+space_in_atx_header+spaced_reference_links+startnum+strikeout+subscript+superscript+table_captions+task_lists+tex_math_dollars+tex_math_double_backslash+yaml_metadata_block
```

Please do not feel so strange with many and many enabled features. My goal is to have all available features for the Markdown framework I am building.

I only do not know which of these features that prevent the conversion of the raw Markdown in the HTML code.

Comment: Remove the indentation from the Markdown text.

Comment: I have just done it, but the raw Markdown wasn't converted either.

Comment: Note: `markdown_github` is deprecated in favour of `gfm` and `markdown_mmd` is just a shorthand for enabling/disabling some extensions, see `pandoc --list-extensions=markdown_mmd`. Please take a look at https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#pandocs-markdown to better understand how pandoc works...